# Aligning in- and out-text for algorithms

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

I use the `algorithm2e` package to typeset algorithms with custom keywords for input and output.

When using `\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}` to define the keywords, colons are added but input and output are not aligned.

[image]

When using `\SetKwInOut{KwInput}{Input}` the text is aligned. However, the colon is at the right, so there will be ugly space like "Input  :" that creates eye cancer.

[image]

**My question is**: How can I get the output (shown in the image below) without fiddling with `\hspace` in every `algorithm` environment?

[image: The result I would like to achieve.]

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

% Define keywords
\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}

% This aligns the colons
%\SetKwInOut{KwInput}{Input}
%\SetKwInOut{KwOutput}{Output}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}[h]
        \KwInput{Network}

        \KwOutput{Flow}

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Start with $\ldots$
        \end{enumerate}
        \caption{Some algorithm.}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\SetKwInOut}[2]{%
  \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo:}%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname InOutSizeDefined\endcsname\relax% if first time used
    \newcommand\InOutSizeDefined{}\setlength{\inoutsize}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo:\hfill}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
  \else% else keep the larger dimension
    \ifdim\wd\algocf@inoutbox>\inoutsize%
    \setlength{\inoutsize}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \sbox\algocf@inoutbox{\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo:\hfill}~}\setlength{\inoutindent}{\wd\algocf@inoutbox}%
    \fi%
  \fi% the dimension of the box is now defined.
  \algocf@newcommand{#1}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{algocf@inoutnumbered}}{\relax}{\everypar={\relax}}%
%     {\let\\\algocf@newinout\hangindent=\wd\algocf@inoutbox\hangafter=1\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo\hfill:}~##1\par}%
    {\let\\\algocf@newinout\hangindent=\inoutindent\hangafter=1\parbox[t]{\inoutsize}{\KwSty{#2}\algocf@typo:\hfill}~##1\par}%
    \algocf@linesnumbered% reset the numbering of the lines
  }}%
\makeatother

% Define keywords
%\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
%\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}

% This aligns the colons
\SetKwInOut{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{KwOutput}{Output}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}[h]
        \KwInput{Network}

        \KwOutput{Flow}

        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Start with $\ldots$
        \end{enumerate}
        \caption{Some algorithm.}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're sticking to a single-line `\KwInput`, you can use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{calc}

% Define keywords
\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}
\let\oldKwInput\KwInput
\renewcommand{\KwInput}[1]{%
  \makebox[\widthof{\KwOutput{}}][l]{\oldKwInput{}#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
  \KwInput{Network}

  \KwOutput{Flow}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Start with $\ldots$
  \end{enumerate}
  \caption{Some algorithm.}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

The above code redefined `\KwInput` by placing `Input:` inside a box of width matching that of `Output:`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an unusual way to achieve it... using `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

% Define keywords
\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}

% This aligns the colons
%\SetKwInOut{KwInput}{Input}
%\SetKwInOut{KwOutput}{Output}

\begin{document}

    \begin{algorithm}[h]
    \tabcolsep=0pt
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll}
        \KwInput{}&Network\\
        \KwOutput{}&Flow
    \end{tabular}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Start with $\ldots$
        \end{enumerate}
        \caption{Some algorithm.}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This limits the Input and Output to a single line. However, [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) would circumvent this limitation.